# Spring MVC & Angular - Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

Tags: angular, spring, rest, spring-mvc, weblogic12c

When I try to set `Content-Type:application/json` I get a CORS error Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

Here is my Cors Override in Spring MVC:

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**").allowCredentials(true).allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE","OPTIONS").allowedHeaders("*").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
}
```

My Post API:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/seanPost", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public  String post(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody TrackFileStatusFindForm form ) {
```

My Request in Angular:

```
options = {
headers: new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
};

this.http.post(this.APP_URL + '/seanPost', JSON.stringify(this.model), this.options)
.subscribe(
    data => {
        this.postId = data;
        console.log(this.postId);
    },
    error => {
    console.log('Error occured', error);
  }
)
```

My Spring project is deployed on WebLogic 12c locally and I am using https if that helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```js
private httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) };
```

Comment: No still getting the same cors issue: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at /seanPost. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Comment: Then you're error is server-side. Can't help you with that, I'm not familiar with spring.

Comment: OK. Thanks for helping :)